# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.11.0, Version=11.0.0.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, telerik

Designing a Windows Phone 8 app in Visual Studio 2013 and I just tried adding the RagGauge control from Telerik onto my page.

When I added I received an exception. if I close the designer in Visual Studio and then open the page again I see the control on the page with the words `RadGauge`. I click this and the exception occurs again.

Exception

```
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.11.0, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Stack Trace
at Telerik.Windows.Controls.Design.GaugeGalleryContainer..ctor(Control galleryUI)
at Telerik.Windows.Controls.Design.DesignTimegalleryAdornerProvider.Activate(ModelItem item)
at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Interaction.AdornerProvider.InvokeActivate(EditingContext context, ModelItem item)
at MS.Internal.Features.AdornerProviderFeatureConnector.FeatureProvidersAdded(ModelItem item, IEnumerable`1 extensions)
at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Policies.PolicyDrivenFeatureConnector`1.OnPolicyItemsChanged(Object sender, PolicyItemsChangedEventArgs e)
at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Policies.ItemPolicy.OnPolicyItemsChanged(PolicyItemsChangedEventArgs e)
at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Policies.SelectionPolicy.OnSelectionChanged(Selection newSelection)
at Microsoft.Windows.Design.ContextItemManager.SubscribeProxy`1.SubscribeContext(ContextItem item)
at Microsoft.Windows.Design.SubscribeContextCallback.Invoke(ContextItem item)
at Microsoft.Windows.Design.EditingContext.DefaultContextItemManager.OnItemChanged(ContextItem item)
at Microsoft.Windows.Design.EditingContext.DefaultContextItemManager.SetValue(ContextItem value)
at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.ViewModel.Extensibility.ExtensibilityManager.SetSelection(Selection selection)
at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.ViewModel.Extensibility.ExtensibilityManager.OnViewModelEarlySceneUpdatePhase(Object sender, SceneUpdatePhaseEventArgs args)
at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.ViewModel.SceneUpdatePhaseEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, SceneUpdatePhaseEventArgs e)
at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.ViewModel.SceneViewModel.FireEarlySceneUpdatePhase(SceneUpdatePhaseEventArgs args)
at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.View.SceneViewUpdateScheduleTask.UpdateEarly()
at Microsoft.Expression.Utility.Scheduler.ScheduleTask.Update()
at Microsoft.Expression.Utility.Scheduler.SchedulingService.DispatchTasksAtPriority(DispatcherPriority priority)
at Microsoft.Expression.Utility.Scheduler.SchedulingService.DispatcherToken.Dispatch(Object arg)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

InnerException: None

Comment: Why dont you ask this que on Telerik website. They have a nice support. They will help you out.

Comment: I have done but I put on here too as I was trying to get the fastest response I could. Anyway, telerik got back to me and it looks like Microsoft has changed something in VS 2013 so telerik are working on the issue.